# AutohotKey assign symbols

Tags: autohotkey

I want to get `<-` when I press alt+s

I use this code below but it does not work. I believe, you cannot put 2 symbols into brackets. How to assign it correctly??

!s::SendInput {<}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!s::SendRaw <-` or `!s::SendInput {<}-`